# Persist data across redis container

Tags: docker, redis

So I have been trying to persist the data of a redis container. I created a host shared folder called /redis-volume and am trying to store the data from redis into it.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to persist data across redis container in docker-compose version 3. And this is what finally worked. Please let me know if this is the right way to do it

```
container_name: redis_db
        command: redis-server --appendonly yes
        image: redis
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
        volumes:
            - ./redis-volume:/data
```

Inside the /redis-volume on the host you will be able to find a file called **appendonly.aof**.
This is what persists data. Also while restarting the container you will be able to find a line like this if you look closely.

```
redis_db      | 1:M 08 Jun 2020 19:40:28.024 * DB loaded from append only file: 0.000 seconds
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You might add these details to the question, and explain what specific problem you're running into.  This seems like a pretty normal Compose/Redis setup though.